# Table set homepage orchard

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

please tell me where to find table that stores certain page as homepage in orchard?

Because just a moment ago I cannot access my home page

The resource cannot be found.

Thanks

Comment: Any error logs or something? Question is to broad...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you do need to change the home page directly through the database, this is done in `Orchard_Autoroute_AutoroutePartRecord`'s `DisplayAlias` column. The first entry with an empty value for `DisplayAlias` is treated as the homepage.

Answer (score 1):

You probably just don't have a page set as your home page. Go to any Page content type and set it as the homepage.